# Faster "IF" statement workaround when choosing between two existing data frame columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
x <- 1000
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c("Jack", "Jill"), x, replace = TRUE),
                 b = sample(c("Bonnie", "Clyde"), x, replace = TRUE),
                 c = sample(c("blue", "green"), x, replace = TRUE))
```

I want to create a new column called df$choice that picks picks `df$a` when `df$c == "blue"` and picks `df$b` when `df$c == "green"`.

Understanding the limitations with traditional `if` and `ifelse` statements in this situation, I created the following function to perform the desired task:

```
choice <- function(y) {
  nw1 <- df[y, ]

  if(nw1$c == "blue") {
    nw1$choice = nw1$a
  } else {
    nw1$choice <- nw1$b
  }

  print(nw1)
}

rows <- c(1:nrow(df))
df2 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(rows, function(y) choice(y)))
```

The elapsed time test when x <- 1000 is a just over 2 seconds, but when inflating x <- 25000, the elapsed function time is over 60 seconds on my machine.

Are there any suggestions of a different way to go about this task to reduce the system.time when dealing in >25000 rows to go through? There is probably a different apply function to do the trick, but I have yet to figure it out.

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized; `if` is not, so you see the former a lot more in R.

Comment: @rawr Not writing loops, no? There are alternatives that make more sense when the number of levels is more than two, but otherwise `ifelse` is concise and snappy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for any function or loops/*`apply`, just set the factors to characters, and use `ifelse` to assign the new column

```
x <- 1000
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c("Jack", "Jill"), x, replace = TRUE),
                 b = sample(c("Bonnie", "Clyde"), x, replace = TRUE),
                 c = sample(c("blue", "green"), x, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = F)


df$choice <- ifelse(df$c == "blue", df$a, df$b)

head(df)
     a      b     c choice
1 Jack Bonnie  blue   Jack
2 Jill Bonnie  blue   Jill
3 Jack  Clyde green  Clyde
4 Jack Bonnie green Bonnie
5 Jill Bonnie green Bonnie
6 Jill Bonnie  blue   Jill
```

Comment: Thanks @Symbolix . I was obviously missing the stringsAsFactors = F portion in my thinking about ifelse.

Comment: @BrandonS - yes, that's a common 'gotcha'!

Answer (score 2):

We can use a simple `row/column` index which would be very fast

```
df$choice <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df),(df$c!="blue")+1L)]
head(df)
#     a      b     c choice
#1 Jill Bonnie green Bonnie
#2 Jill  Clyde green  Clyde
#3 Jill  Clyde green  Clyde
#4 Jill  Clyde  blue   Jill
#5 Jack  Clyde  blue   Jack
#6 Jack  Clyde green  Clyde
```